# Create project files from template files using Revit API and design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am working in an engineering company and we deal a lot with `Revit` templates such as Structure and MEP 
 architecture ...etc every time we need to create a project based on one of our templates we need to do something like creating work-set and link files...etc, I was thinking to use Autodesk forge design automation in order to achieve an automated result. like a simple web app `input(set the name)` of work-sets, and push it to the could forge design automation and download the file when it's ready.
the whole idea to save time, instead, each user opens Revit chose a template to select what type of setting you need to work on... I want to automate the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly possible. You can do almost anything you like that is possible using the pure DB Revit API, with no UI interaction. The Building Coder topic group on [DA4R – Design Automation for Revit](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.55) includes some examples of how to proceed to prepare your desktop Revit add-in for migration to DA4R.

Comment: Hi Jeremy,
so your point is to build a small add-in that generates an automatic RVT project from a template? but I need to open Revit and the template and after that use, my add-in to build a new project with settings that I have made via my add-in?  let's say we succeed doing that how Forge Design automation will understand that I am having a template to generate the project file... I know it's a bit complicated :)

Comment: My suggestion is described in the blog posts. Implement and test your add-in on the desktop, then migrate it to DA4R.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the topic that Jeremy offered, you can find more tutorials on converting a Revit Add-In into a Design Automation for Revit app here:  https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/

Comment: hi, Michael thank you for replying, I am still facing a hard time to understand how Forge Design automation will understand that I am having a Revit template to generate the project file, please a look on the comment below.